# How can to make Object.assign and spread operator work on all browsers?

Tags: webpack

How can I make Object.assign work on ie and ... spread operator work on all browsers.
The following is my webpack config file.

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '../../public/admin-portal/js'),
    publicPath: '../../public/admin-portal/js',
    filename: 'app.js'
  },
  plugins: [
  ],
  // support source maps
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /tinymce[\\/]skins[\\/]/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=[path][name].[ext]&context=node_modules/tinymce'
      },
      { test: /\.html$/, exclude: /node_modules|bower_components/, use: ['html-loader'] },
      { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules|bower_components/, use: ['babel-loader?presets=es2015'] },
      { test: /\.css$/, exclude: /node_modules|bower_components/, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] },
      { test: /\.scss$/, exclude: /node_modules|bower_components/, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'] },
      // // load images (inline base64 URLs for <=30k images)
      { test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/, exclude: /node_modules|bower_components/, use: ['url-loader?limit=30720'] }
    ]
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply import [core-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js) or [es6-shim](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-shim) to support `Object.assign`, but it looks like you'd need to use [babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/) to get `spread`.